# gruntfile taskrunner compilation error in angular js 2 project

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, gruntjs

I am working on asp.net project using angular js 2 in VS 2015. I am using webpack and gruntfile. I have a task in task runner which is giving error like this:

```
Running "ts:base" (ts) task
Compiling...
Using tsc v2.0.6
>> Compilation failed
Warning: Task "ts:base" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
Process terminated with code 3.
```

It is like this http://prntscr.com/ht6mo6

When I load the project, it shows these errors in console:

(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for a: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
    Error: Can't resolve all parameters for a: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

Error is like this in chrome dev tools

http://prntscr.com/ht6nlc

I notice that node_modules folder is created in root of project not in wwwroot. Is it cause of error?

Please suggest me how to fix these or troubleshoot these errors.

Thanks.